# how to mange role Assignment by action wise in MVC3 i.e.each role be assign by different Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, role

How to manage role Assignment by action wise in MVC3, i.e. each role is assigned by a different Action in MVC3 in C#.net ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict access to given actions you could decorate them with the [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute and specify the roles that are allowed to access it:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    ...
}
```